# A Fallacious Argument on Open Cover of Rationals in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, the set of rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$, and suppose that $\left(c_{k}\right)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ denotes an ordered enumeration of the elements of $A$. Then, given $\epsilon>0$, consider an open interval cover $\left(I_{k}\right)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of $A$ defined by $I_{k} = \left(c_{k}-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{k}},c_{k}+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{k}}\right)$ for all $k$.

---

Question: Is it correct to argue that at most countably many irrationals could have been left out from being covered by the union $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}$? If so, can someone please provide a proof of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if $\epsilon<1/2$, then no, since the measure of the union is at most $2\epsilon$.

Comment: @M.T So, can I argue that if it were the case that at most countably many irrationals are left out, then collecting those irrationals into a set (say $B$), we have $[0,1] \subset \left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}\right) \bigcup B$, and hence $\lambda([0,1])\leq \lambda\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}I_{k}\right) +\lambda(B)$. Now the RHS is $2\epsilon$, while the LHS is $1$, and this relation might not hold if $\epsilon < \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yeah, you can argue like that.

Comment: @M.T Thank you for pointing me to this subtlety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be uncountably many irrationals not in $\bigcup_{k-1}^{\infty} I_k$ (depending on $\varepsilon$ of course). To see this, let $
\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Then $\lambda I_k = \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{k-1}}$.  Then it would follow that 
$ \lambda(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} I_k) \leq \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda(I_k) = \varepsilon  \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} = 2\varepsilon$.
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, this is a contradiction.

Comment: You can't say it _is not_ an open cover. You're correct that it _may not be_ an open cover...

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I'll edit it.